# Is there any programmtical way where I can remove class of list item

Tags: javascript

I am doing one loop where I am matching with some value and assigning `class="hidden"` to list. But When I run again the loop I want all my list should be without class, so I can assign for other value.

Here is my code.

```
for (i = list.children.length; i--;) {
            li = list.children[i];
            match = li.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1;
            li.classList.toggle('hidden', !match)
        }
```

But before I run this loop I want all the list without any class so hete in the list I want to remove `Class="hidden"`

```
<li class="hidden">
            <a href="#">Albania</a>
        </li>
```

Can anyone help me to achieve this

Comment: li.classList.classlist.remove('hidden')?

Answer (score 2):

You want to do this before your existing loop? Try this:

```js
var list = document.getElementById("list");
for (i = list.children.length; i--;) {
  li = list.children[i];
  li.classList.remove("hidden");
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li class="hidden">foo</li>
  <li>bar</li>
  <li class="hidden">baz</li>
</ul>
```

Though it does look like you could do this in the beginning of your existing loop. No need for another loop before that one.

Comment: Ya, That will help to restart from fresh. Any other suggestion are also welcome

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a combo of `Element.classList.contains(), ..remove(), ..add()` etc. Lots of info on the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

For example:

```
for(i=list.children.length; i--;) {
    li = list.children[i];
    if (li.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
        li.classList.add('hidden');
        // or is it li.classList.remove('hidden'); here?
    }
}
```

It is safe to `..add()` even if the element has the class already. The class will not be added twice.